# Parsing gitignore in bash/coreutils without git

Tags: bash, git, shell, plasticscm

My goal is to copy all files from a directory except those that are specified in an ignore file to another directory. However, imagine git is not installed (it's using Plastic SCM, but the ignore format is identical to gitignore for all intents and purposes). How would you go about doing this in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strips out comments and empty lines from the ignore file:

```bash
grep -v '^#' ~/.config/git/ignore | grep '[^[:blank:]]'
```

Join those lines with a pipe character and capture in a variable

```bash
ignores=$(grep -v '^#' ~/.config/git/ignore | grep '[^[:blank:]]' | paste -sd '|')
```

Enagle extended globbing

```bash
shopt -s extglob nullglob
```

and now this will show the non-ignored files *in the current directory*

```bash
echo !($ignores)
```

---

to find non-ignored files descending into directories, this might work (I don't know the git internals, this is a guess)

```bash
# read the ignores into an array
readarray -t ign < <(grep -v '^#' ~/.config/git/ignore | grep '[^[:blank:]]')

# construct find options
find_opts=()
for i in "${ign[@]}"; do find_opts+=( -o -name "$i" ); done

# do it
find . -type f \
       -not '(' "${find_opts[@]:1}" ')' \
       -exec printf 'do something with: %s\n' {} +
```